# UIApplication sharedApplication openURL only work once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button when user click it and it launch the map app to show the direction to the destination.

```
 NSURL *mapURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mapURL];
```

and I found on iOS 8.1 it only opens once and it won't work the second time or third time.
I had to uninstall the app and re-install it again to make it work.

And the view was nested in a navigation hierarchy.

any ideas?

Comment: Is there anything else in the method this is being called in?

Comment: are you implementing this method?: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url